# eql? missing one argument error in erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to have a if condition in a erb file. But when I write like this, I get an error

```
<% if login_authority.eql? 'super' || login_authority.eql? 'admin'%>
```

For the second expression `"login_authority.eql? 'admin'"`
I got a

```
 Missing 1 argument(s). Require 1
```

But I have an argument 'admin'. This is very weird.

Comment: Just curious, you got missing argument error from this code? I think it is equivalent to ` if login_authority.eql? ('super' || login_authority.eql?) 'admin'` and so you'll get 'unexpected tSTRING_BEG` error instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting them in brackets or remove spaces.

```
login_authority.eql?('super') || login_authority.eql?('admin')
```

**OR**

```
login_authority.eql?"super" || login_authority.eql?"admin"
```